# Books for Self learning math from the ground up

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I am a CSE graduate currently working as a .NET and android developer. I feel my poor basic in mathematics is hampering my improvements as a programmer.

I want to achieve a sound understanding on the basics of mathematics so that i can pick up a book on 3D graphics programming/Algorithm and not be intimidated by all the maths(linear algebra,discrete mathematics... etc. ) used in it.

So, what path/resource/book one should follow to create a good foundation on mathematics?

Thank you

P.S. I have read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69060/what-is-a-good-book-for-learning-math-from-the-ground-up) but i wanted to know other/better options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommend books for learning math from elementary school?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/824047/recommend-books-for-learning-math-from-elementary-school)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 2):

Let me propose a different tack since you have a clear goal. Pick up a book on 3D graphics programming or algorithms, and if you come across something that intimidates you too much to get by on your own, ask about it here. We will be able to direct you to exact references to better understand the material in this way. Conceivably, there might be a little bit of recursion, and that's okay.

Comment: that's one way to look at it .... must admit this is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a book on basic maths, but very enjoyable and starts from the basic and builds up, lets you work through concepts, and also relates deeply to programming, algorithms, and such like is: The Art of Computer Programming by Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

The [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html) by W. W. Chen are accessible, just pick what you require in there. The books published by [The Trillia Group](http://www.trillia.com/) are nice too (the number theory one is rough going!). If you are interested in math for computer science, the lecture notes at MIT for their [6.042](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/) class cover everything you'd want to ask. All of the above are available in PDF for free.

As the answer by @mixedmath states, start with what you need and drill down. Make sure you understand how proofs work (the MIT notes start with that, and are quite clear). If you get stuck, sleep it over and try again. *Do* the exercises, at least enough to feel confortable you've got the hang of the matter. If *really* stumped, ask here or at http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Good luck!