# personal enrichment in science and, particularly, in math

Tags: education, self-learning

What is the best way to expand one's area of thought 
in science and especially in math? Read scientific journals 
or view some conferences? What else?

Comment: You might want to search this site for recommendations along these lines, for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365175/how-to-fill-gaps-in-my-math-knowledge?rq=1 Regards